# Remover elemento de una lista que coincida con elemento de otra lista

Tags: c#

Tengo dos listas de string, con los siguientes valores:

Lista A:

- '9999'
- '1111'

Lista B:

- '1111'

Quiero remover de la lista A los elementos que coincidan con alguno de la lista B.
En este caso quedaría:

Lista C:

- '9999'

Estaba buscando alguna forma optima de realizarlo pero no se me ocurre ninguna, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: que has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo tengo estas listas:

```
List<int> lista1 = new List<int>() { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
            List<int> lista2 = new List<int>() { 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 };
```

Puedes aplicar la siguiente función de linq para remover todos los elementos de `lista1`, que tenga `lista2`:

```
lista1.RemoveAll(x => lista2.All(y => y != x));
```

El método `RemoveAll` elimina de una lista, todos los elementos que concuerden con el query especificado. El método `All`, devuelve todos los elementos que concuerden con el query especificado. entonces, en `lista2`, obtenemos todos los que existan en `lista1`, y en `lista1`, los removemos de sus elementos.
Finalmente, si deseas imprimirlos o algo así, puedes recorrer lo que quedó en `lista1`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Elementos de lista1:\n");
            foreach (int id in lista1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
            }
```

¡Saludos!

Comment: Genial! Al final lo resolvi utilizando Except. Dejo un ejemplo:
List<Integer> result = listA.Except(listB).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Para remover elementos de una lista lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
A.RemoveAll(x => B.Contains(x));
```

Remueves de la lista A todos los elementos que estén contenidos en la lista B.

Si lo que quieres es no removerlos y crear una lista C como lo planteas lo puedes hacer así.

```
C = A.Where(x => !B.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

En la lista C agregas los elementos de la lista A que no están contenidos en la lista B.